# Move assignment operator and exceptions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I have a couple of questions about move assignment operator and possibly thrown exceptions:

1. Provided that `is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value` is true for the type `T`, is it enough to conclude that move assignment operator for that type will never throw an exception? In other words, is it ok to have this `noexcept` specification:

```cpp
    struct MyClass
    {
        MyClass& operator = (MyClass&& other) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<OtherClass>::value)
        {
            this->data = std::move(other.data);
            return *this;
        }
    
        OtherClass data;
    };
```

(Let's assume that we cannot rely on defaulted move-assignment operator)

2. Talking specifically about `std::vector`, in C++11 its move-assignment operator may throw implementation-defined exceptions (according to the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D)). And even since C++17 its `noexcept` specification still depends on the allocator traits. But this is a general case. Let's say we have two instrances of `std::vector<double>` with default allocator. Is it still possible that move assignment throws an exception in this case?

```cpp
    std::vector<double> v1{ 1,2,3 }, v2{4,5};
    v1 = std::move(v2);  // can it throw?
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No.`noexcept` keyword says only, that it does not suppose to throw any exception and compiler will *assume* that the function will not throw exception, thus it will not produce exception-handing code. If noexcept function will throw an exception, the program will be terminated immediately. Thus said, I believe, using `noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<OtherClass>::value)` is enough.
2. Lets take a look at the standard and cppreference:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D :

```cpp
noexcept(std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value
|| std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::is_always_equal::value)
```

- `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value`, standard says([allocator.requirements])

> If X::propagate_on_-
> container_move_assignment::value is true, X shall satisfy the MoveAssignable requirement and the move operation shall not throw exceptions.

the `double` type is plain old builtin type, so it satisfies MoveAssignable requirements (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable) and thus exception should not be thrown.

- `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::is_always_equal::value` is true

In `noexcept` statement binary OR is used, so it shall not throw any exceptions.

Comment: Well, I know what noexcept means, but immediate termination is definitely not a desired behavior, that's why I want noexcept condition to be true only if no exception can be thrown. The point 1 is a bit unclear to me. When you said "No", did you mean that move-assignment can throw despite std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value being true? In the point 2 you seem to be referring to C++17 specification. How about C++11? And how do you know that std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value is true for vector<double>?

Comment: `nothrow(true)` does not mean "no exceptions will ever happen during the operation of the function, relax, be relieved, all is well". It rather means "I guarantee that no exception will ever leak out of a call of this function (and, oh, btw, if I happen to encounter an uncaught exception, I'll terminate the app just so I can keep my guarantee)".

Comment: @mentalmushroom 
1. If someone wants to throw an exception, it is thrown and `noexcept` can't stop from it. But that's no problem, since if someone writes `noexcept` function that actully throws an exception, that _someone_ is to blame, that is not your problem.
2. Yes, I did mean, that move-assignment can throw despite std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value being true. That template is using `noexcept` keyword.

Comment: @mentalmushroom 
3. Yep, `std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<double>::value` and `std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<std::vector<double>>::value` are true. It is true because move-assigning double cannot throw exceptions (moving double is the same as assigning double another value), for std::vector<double> take a look at my answer.
4. `std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<double>::value` is guaranteed to be true in C++11, what's about `std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<std::vector<double>>::value`, it "May throw implementation-defined exceptions.".

Comment: @mentalmushroom 
5. Because in the default allocator `propagate_on_container_move_assignment`  equals `true_type`.

Comment: The `nothrow` expression as well as the statement beginning `X::propagate_on...` that are cited in this answer are properties of the allocator (the `X` here is the allocator class), not properties of the value type. In a `std::vector<double>`, the default allocator is used, and its properties are such that it never throws an exception when *it* (the allocator, not the values that it allocates) are moved.

Comment: Corollary: the move assignment operator of `std::vector<double>` and in fact of every `std::vector<T>` for every `T` whatsoever is `nothrow(true)`.